# Calculating Kernel Density within defined region?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, kernel-density

I am attempting to calculate a Kernel density raster dataset from a point dataset within a defined regional boundary. However the output dataset generated is in a large square that cuts off one of the corners of this geographic boundary.

Is there a method to calculate the Kernel density within this polygon boundary?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [Extent](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/output-extent.htm) and [Mask](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/mask.htm) environments to match your polygon boundary. Simply select that layer from the dropwdowns when setting the environments or specify the file's path.

This way the resulting raster file will match the extent of your boundary and all pixels that fall outside the polygon will be converted to NoData.